# NSNotification...the right way?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios, nsnotifications

I have an tab bar app and the 2 tabs use the same class (different instances) to show a UITableView. Based on which tab is clicked a few minor changes are made to the appearance, functionality etc. The problem I have is that from the UITableView I show a modal view and when it is dismissed it posts an NSNotification to reload the UITableView (handled by the UITableView's view controller), but I get 2 NSNotifications posted as there are 2 instances of the same class in my app. How can I get the notification be be posted in just the instance it is called from?

Comment: What do you mean by 'there are 2 instances of the same call in my app'? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Oops, 'class' not 'call'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set up a handler for an `NSNotification` you can specify an `object`  for whose notifications you are interested in.

You should set your first table view controller to only be interested in notifications that are posted from the specific instance of the modal view controller, and your second table view controller to only be interested in notifications posted from *its* specific instance of the modal view controller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handler:)
                                             name:notificationName 
                                           object:instanceOfModalViewController];
```

This way when a notification is posted from your modal view controller, only the table view controller that has specified its interest will handle the notification.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Will I need to remove the notification in a different place to the dealloc (as it is currently) so as not to duplicate notifications when pressing the button that shows the modal view (this is where I create the notification now too)?

Comment: You should probably inform the `NSNotificationCenter` that you want to start listening just as you are about to display the modal view controller. Then you should stop listening (by calling `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:notificationName object:instanceOfModalViewController];`) just after you've handled the notification.

Comment: I'll probably have to remove them some other way because the notification is not always called the the modal view is dismissed, thanks for your help though!